# opendj: missing attribute cn which is required by objectclass person

Tags: opendj

I am new to OpenDJ. We are trying to make a entry but getting the following error in the access log.

> [01/Mar/2016:10:03:45 +0000] ADD REQ conn=4 op=7 msgID=8
>   dn="uid=U-y-000000000,ou=Org-0,dc=ericsson,dc=com"
>
> [01/Mar/2016:10:03:45 +0000] ADD RES conn=4 op=7 msgID=8 result=65
>   message="Entry uid=U-y-000000000,ou=Org-0,dc=ericsson,dc=com violates
>   the Directory Server schema configuration because it is missing
>   attribute cn which is required by objectclass person" etime=5 ^C

Answer (score 2):

I think the error cannot be more explicit:

You are trying to add an entry to OpenDJ, with an objectClass Person (or its family such as inetOrgPerson). The Person requires that you provide a commonName (cn) attribute with at least one value.

This is a basis of LDAP and any LDAP server will return a similar error, when you try to add an entry that is not compliant with the standard schema.

Comment: Hi, after installing opendj, I am using a script to make schema that my application needs
 _#create attributes and objectClasses
./ldapmodify -a --hostName $HOST --port $PORT --bindDN "$ROOT_USER_DN" --bindPassword $PASSWORD --trustAll --useSSL -f $MODEL_FILE

#import the initialize data
./import-ldif --ldifFile $DATA_FILE --backendID $BACKEND  --clearBackend --hostName $HOST --port $PORT --bindDN "$ROOT_USER_DN" --bindPassword $PASSWORD --trustAll --noPropertiesFile_

Comment: $MODEL_FILE: _dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( userEmailAddress-oid NAME 'userEmailAddress' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE USAGE userApplications X-SCHEMA-FILE '99-user.ldif' )


dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( user-oid NAME 'user' SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL MUST ( uid $ userPassword) MAY ( userEmailAddress ) X-SCHEMA-FILE '99-user.ldif' )_

Comment: $DATA_FILE _dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: example
description: This is the People container
telephoneNumber: ***********

dn: ou=Org-0,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit
ou: Org-0
description: This is the Org-0 organizational unit_

Comment: I am not using any schema name "person".

Comment: Where is the ldif for adding dn="uid=U-y-000000000,ou=Org-0,dc=ericsson,dc=com" ? This is where the error is.

Comment: correction: I have modified $DATA_FILE _dc=example_ to _dc=ericsson_ . We are inserting this data via our internal application. Is there anyway opendj can capture what is sent to it from our application? I'll also try to find what data is sent by our application from wireshark logs.

Comment: HI, Found that my application is not sending any AttributeValue: for AttributeList item cn. I think the problem is at our application end.